# From Riemann tensor to Ricci tensor and vice versa

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

Is it possible to find the Riemann tensor using the Ricci tensor and also to switch from Riemann $(0,4)$ to Riemann $(1,3)$?

I am not clear if these operations can only be carried out in one sense, I will explain better with these two questions.

1) $g^{bd}R_{abcd}=R_{ac}$, where $R_{abcd}$ it is Riemann $(0,4)$ and $R_{ac}$ it is the Ricci tensor, is it now possible to get the Riemann tensor $(0,4)$ again this way: $R_{ac} g_{bd}=R_{abcd}$?

2) $g_{ae}R^a_{bcd}=R_{ebcd}$, where $R^a_{bcd}$ it ise the Riemann $(1,3)$ and $R_{ebcd}$ it is the Riemann $(0,4)$, is it now possible to get the Riemann tensor $(1,3)$ again this way:  $g^{ae}R_{ebcd}=R^a_{bcd}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're not allowed to use any index more than twice, $R_{ac}g_{bd}=R_{aecf}g^{ef}g_{bd}$, which can't be simplified to $R_{abcd}$, so 1) doesn't work. But 2) is correct because$$g^{ae}R_{ebcd}=g^{ae}g_{fe}R^f_{\:bcd}=\delta^a_fR^f_{\:bcd}=R^a_{\:bcd}.$$You may also find [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77973/riemann-tensor-in-2d-and-3d) discussion of $2$- or $3$-dimensional manifolds interesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I still don't understand why 2) it works.

Comment: @exxxit8 See edit.